# Powershell foreach math issue. Sum is cumulative, not foreach server polled

Tags: powershell

Trying to script a daily "check" on DHCP usage. Pulling info from DHCP servers using netsh, looking at IP addresses in use and available, removing letters and delimiting characters so all I have left is the raw number of addresses. Then add them up to get total address pool size and finish with % in use. I've been futzing with this for a few days now, and finally got something I liked, but my math doesn't work right. Some remote sites have multiple scopes/subnets, and when trying to add those numbers into a per-server total, and instead it just adds addresses cumulatively. I think my problem is the final "foreach" in $u and $f, but I'm not sure how to fix it and get what I want. If I remove the final foreach, it works fine for single subnet sites but can't handle more on any one server. I hope that made sense.

```
function dhcp {
  $servers = "contoso","contoso2","contoso3"
  Foreach ($server in $servers)
  {
    netsh dhcp server \\$server show server
    "DHCP Server: $server"
    #netsh dhcp server \\$server show mibinfo | select-string -pattern "scope", "subnet", "No. of Addresses in use = ", "No. of free Addresses = "
    $u = (netsh dhcp server \\$server show mibinfo | 
         where-object {$_-match "No. of Addresses in use = "}  | 
         foreach-object{$_.Split(“=")[-1].Trim( ).Trim(".").Trim(" ")} | 
         foreach-object{($u2+=[int]$_)})
    $f = (netsh dhcp server \\$server show mibinfo | 
         where-object {$_-match "No. of free Addresses = "} | 
         foreach-object{$_.Split(“=")[-1].Trim().Trim(".").Trim(" ")} | 
         foreach-object{($f2+=[int]$_)})
    $total2 = ([int]$u2+[int]$f2)
    $percent = [Math]::Round([int]$u2/[int]$total2*100,2)
    "No. of Addresses in use = $u2"
    "No. of free Addresses = $f2"
    "Total Addresses: $total2" 
    "Percent in use: $percent%"
    "                ======"
    "=================================================="
  } 
}
dhcp | out-file "C:\Users\crabbypatty\Desktop\Powershell\dhcplog $(get-date -f MM-dd-HHmm).txt"
```

Comment: I don't understand the input format, but might this be as simple as setting your variables to zero at the top of the first loop? Meaning right after your "netsh dhcp server \\$server show server", set u2 and f2 both back to zero?

Comment: That's it!! Oh man, I'm such an ass....never even thought about statically assigning a value of 0 to them. Brilliant!! Thanks Gargantu!!!  The input is just a list of dhcp server dns names, which had been changed to protect the innocent.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll repost as an actual answer. Thanks for the feedback. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify this significantly by using capture groups in your regex and also using the switch condition's ability to process regular expressions.

Oh and I'd use a dictionary to ensure that each server is tracked individually while allowing you to access the data after the capture is complete. This would also give you the ability to do some historical tracking and comparison if you saved the data... but that's outside of this scope ;)

e.g.

```
    $addressesInUse = @{};
    $addressesFree = @{};

    foreach ($server in $serverList) {
        $mibinfo = netsh dhcp server \\$server show mibinfo; #| where-object {$_-match "No. of Addresses in use = "}  |
        foreach ($info in $mibinfo) {
            switch -regex ($info) {
                "No. of Addresses in use = (?<count>\d+)" {
                    $val = $Matches["count"]; 
                    if ($addressesInUse.ContainsKey($server)) {
                        $addressesInUse.Add($server,$val);
                    } else {
                        $scopeCount.$server += $val;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                "No. of free Addresses = (?<count>\d+)" {
                    $val = [int]::Parse($Matches["count"]);
                    if ($addressesFree.ContainsKey($server)) {
                        $addressesFree.Add($server,$val);
                    } else {
                        $addressesFree.$server += $val;
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($key in $addressesFree.keys) {
        $total = $addressesInUse.$key + $addressesFree.$key;
        $percent = [Math]::Round($addressesInUse.$server / $total*100,2)
        Write-Host ("DHCP availablility for server {0}" -f $key);
        Write-Host ("No. of Addresses in use = {0}" -f $addressesInUse.$key);
        Write-Host ("No. of free Addresses = {0}" -f $addressesFree.$key);
        Write-Host ("Total Addresses: {0}" -f $total);
        Write-Host ("Percent in use: {0}%" - $percent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might this be as simple as setting your variables to zero at the top of the first loop? Meaning right after your "netsh dhcp server \$server show server", set u2 and f2 both back to zero?

```
Foreach ($server in $servers) {
    netsh dhcp server \\$server show server
    "DHCP Server: $server"
```

At this point, reset the variables:

```
    $f2 = 0
    $u2 = 0
```